# I designing a pulse generation circuit using capacitor and resistor but my output is not coming as expected

Tags: capacitor, passive-networks, pulse, signal-generator, edge-detection

I am designing a pulse circuit which I will be feeding to a comparator. I am using a combination of resistor capacitor and diode for generating positive edge triggered pulse as shown in the below figure (encircled in the yellow color). I want some guidance how to design such circuit to generate that kind of pulse.[image: positive edge triggered circuit]
[image: The encircled part which I looking to implement]

Comment: What are we seeing here? Show your circuit and a clear waveform you are expecting from it.

Comment: Hii Eugene I am still not designed proper circuit . I am just using simple RC circuit to generate pulse

Comment: That looks flipped horizontally from what you'd get from an RC circuit.

Comment: I want waveform which is encircled. That is the only waveform I need to generate

Comment: Hii Hearth that what I am thinking but I don't know how to proceed!

Comment: You can't get such a waveform. It look exponentially rising, which can't happen in RC circuit.

Comment: You said that your output is not coming as expected. So you already have a circuit that doesn’t work. Show that circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don’t know how to design it, so how can you claim that you can design it just using a resistor, a capacitor, and a diode?
2. What does it mean that the circuit is edge-triggered? Please draw the. *input* to the circuit as well as the *output* you expect. Don’t just paste some 3rd party picture - draw it yourself, even by hand on paper, take a picture, and edit the question to include the information.

Generally, for edge triggering, you’ll want the functional equivalent of a flip-flop: once the flip-flop’s output goes high, it charges a capacitor through a resistor. Then the comparator triggers and re-sets the flip flop, as well as discharges the capacitor. All this is done in the 555 timer, so you can just use that IC.

As for constraining the end-of-charge threshold by a cycloid waveform (the “half circles” on your picture): that is an interesting problem to solve if you want to limit yourself to purely analog techniques. In the world of analog computing, this would be usually solved using a diode-based function generator block that takes “time” as an input voltage (ramp), and outputs the cycloid. You can get reasonable precision that way, even though it is an approximation.

Otherwise, you’d need an inverse-cosine function to convert time into angle, and feed that angle into a sine function to get the cycloïdal shape. This can be done precisely without approximation, but only in discrete time. First, time input is a voltage ramp. Then, a fast cosine waveform is synchronized to two sawtooth waves that represent the angle: one with 0 degree offset for cosine, another with -90 degree offset for sine. When the cosine matches the input ramp, the 0 degree ramp is sampled - that’s the inverse cosine, or the angle at a given point in time. Then when the inverse cosine sample matches the sine sawtooth, the cosine sample is taken - that’s the sine, or the vertical coordinate of the cycloid. This discrete-time sampled cycloid generator can be implemented rather simply using op-amps, comparators, and analog switches (or transistors), and with due care can be quite accurate - better than 0.1% error for sure. It’s not a trivial endeavor though, and it requires precision parts.

Comment: Hii kuba as per your suggestion I have added the by project block diagram. The encircled thing is which I am looking to implement

Comment: Hi kuba I like to mention that this a DC-DC converter on which I am working but the closed loop part is which  I am planning to implement from a conference research paper.

Comment: How will you generate the carrier? Is the carrier a cycloid, or is it just someone’s broken idea of a square sine or absolute sine? The carrier is the hard part. The RC circuit is elementary.

Comment: Kuba the carrier is double integration of step signal ( clock pulse) . That is actually a parabolic signal  which I am getting ( in MATLAB SIMULATION environment).

Comment: Are you asking how to design real circuit or simulate stuff? I’m really confused as to what you already have. You say that you want a circuit: what are the inputs? All those clock pulses and such: they are not drawings on paper, right? What are the actual voltage vs. time parameters of those waveforms? Low and high state voltage, slew rate, repetition rate, … If you want a circuit and not an idea, you’ll have to share everything you’ve accomplished thus far - show oscilloscope traces of the signals coming into the pulse circuit you want.

Comment: Also, that parabolic shape… man, you couldn’t draw an actual parabola? A cycloid is not a parabola!

Comment: Kuba i really understand about your expectations. Actually I am just doing simulation and not any hardware design. I currently doing my simulation in MATLAB. If possible can you share you mail id to which I can share my MATLAB simulation file. I Think it will be very helpful for you questions you asked